# Summarizing count and conditional aggregate functions on the same factor

Tags: r, dplyr

Quick and short of it is I'm having problems summarizing count and aggregate functions with conditions on the same factor.

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(company = c("Acme", "Meca", "Emca", "Acme", "Meca", "Emca"), 
             year = c("2011", "2010", "2009", "2011", "2010", "2013"), 
             product = c("Wrench", "Hammer", "Sonic Screwdriver", "Fairy Dust", "Kindness", "Helping Hand"), 
             price = c("5.67", "7.12", "12.99", "10.99", NA, FALSE))
```

which creates this dataframe (in essence):

```
   company year  product             price
1    Acme  2011  Wrench              5.67
2    Meca  2010  Hammer              7.12
3    Emca  2009  Sonic Screwdriver   12.99
4    Acme  2011  Fairy Dust          10.99
5    Meca  2010  Kindness            NA
...  ...   ...   ...                 ...
n    Emca  2013  Helping Hand        FALSE
```

Let's say I want to `df <- group_by(df, company, year, product)` and then get the following info all in one collection (i.e. dataframe):

1. Count of each price listing (including NA, False)
2. Count of each with 'NA' condition
3. Average price excluding NA and False
4. Max price

   ```
   summarize(df, count = n()) #satisfies first item obviously
   ```

I'm having issues trying to get the others.  I think I need to use pipe operators? If so, can anyone provide some guidance?

This is what I've tried and it is blatantly wrong, but I'm not sure where to go next:

```
 summarize(df,
           total.count = n(),
           count = filter(df, is.na(price)),
           avg.price = filter(df, !is.na(price), price != FALSE),
           max.price = max(filter(df, !is.na(price), price != FALSE))
```

And yes, I have reviewed documentation and I'm sure the answers are there, but they might be too advanced for my understanding.

Comment: In the example dataset, `NAs` are `factor` levels.  So, `is.na` returns FALSE.  Is it the case in your original dataset?.  When you create example data, please don't use `"NA"`, it will read as `character` and then convert to factor when `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is not specified.  Just use `NA`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming that your original dataset is similar to the one you created (i.e. with `NA` as `character`.  You could specify `na.strings` while reading the data using `read.table`.  But, I guess NAs would be detected automatically.

The `price` column is `factor` which needs to be converted to `numeric` class.  When you use `as.numeric`, all the non-numeric elements (i.e. `"NA"`, FALSE) gets coerced to `NA`) with a warning.

```
library(dplyr)    
df |>
     mutate(price = as.numeric(as.character(price))) |>
     summarise(total.count = n(),
               count = sum(is.na(price)),
               avg.price = mean(price, na.rm = TRUE),
               max.price = max(price, na.rm = TRUE),
               .by = c(company, year, product))
```

###data

I am using the same `dataset` (except the `...` row) that was showed.

```
df = tbl_df(data.frame(company=c("Acme", "Meca", "Emca", "Acme", "Meca","Emca"),
 year=c("2011", "2010", "2009", "2011", "2010", "2013"), product=c("Wrench", "Hammer",
 "Sonic Screwdriver", "Fairy Dust", "Kindness", "Helping Hand"), price=c("5.67",
 "7.12", "12.99", "10.99", "NA",FALSE)))
```

Comment: Bad example set, but your answer does provide some very useful guidance.  Much appreciated!